# Crashed when back to MainPage because of using SKGLView

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, skiasharp

> SIGABRT: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SKGLView'.

We are using `SKGLView` in **MainPage**, sometimes back from another view, this error will show and app crash. I have no idea, and here is the log from App Center.

> NSObject.get_SuperHandle ()
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:471
> GLKView.Display ()
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/GLKit/GLKView.g.cs:152
> SKGLViewRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__1 ()
> NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply ()
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:152
> (wrapper managed-to-native)
> UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
> UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal,
> System.IntPtr delegate)
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
> Application.Main (System.String[] args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we solve it just by setting `HasRenderLoop` property for **SKGLView** using code, not in `Xaml`.

Reference link: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/870